# Array.Join in .Net?

Tags: arrays, join, .net-2.0

Ok, this is a dumb thing that I'm sure I've done dozens of times but for some reason I can't find it.

I have an array... And want to get a string with the contents of that array separated by a delimited...

Where is the .Join() method that I can't find?

(This is .Net 2.0, I don't have any LINQ stuff)

Thank you!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you're working with strings, then [`String.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join) is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 35):

It is on the string class

```
String.Join(",", new string[] {"a", "b", "c"});
```

Edit for ints to string

```
 int[] integers = new int[] { 1,2,3,4,5 };
 String.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll<int, String>(integers, Convert.ToString));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have an array of `strings` you can call [`String.join(String, String[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx). You can use it even if you don't have an array of `strings`, you just have to be able to convert your `objects` to `strings`

```
object[] objects = ...
string[] strings = new string[objects.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
  strings[i] = objects[i].ToString();
string value = String.Join(", ", strings);
```

Comment: My friend you are a beautiful person, this is exactly what I needed. I pray you have a good life thanks for saving me hours of work!

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim arrStrIds() As String = Array.ConvertAll(arrIntIds, New Converter(Of Integer, String)(
 Function(id As Integer) id.ToString()) )

String.Join(",", arrStrIds)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use LINQ to Objects and save yourself a few lines

```
int [] ints = { 0, 1, 2 };
string[] intStrings = (from i in ints select i.ToString()).ToArray<string>();
string joinedStrings = string.Join(",", intStrings);
```

Oops, Just saw that you don't have LINQ, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the method in the [String class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx).

**Example using Split and Join:**

```
 public static void Main() { 

    string str = "on two three, four five six."; 
    char[] separators = {' ', '.', ',' }; 

    // Split the string:
    string[] parts = str.Split(separators); 

    string allTogether = String.Join(" | ", parts); 

    Console.WriteLine("Joined: "); 
    Console.WriteLine(allTogether); 


  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to convert the array into a string array in .NET Framework 4. i don't know about previous Frameworks. so the previous code spends several lines converting your int array into a string array. just skip that step (if it also works in your Framework).

```
string[] sA = "11,12,13".Split(',');
int[] iA = { 21, 22, 23};
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("+", iA) + " -- " + string.Join("+", sA));

/* displays:
21+22+23 -- 11+12+13
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really like the ergonomics of Array.Join, you can add an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) like this:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions {
    public static string Join(this IEnumerable<string> arr, string seperator) =>
        string.Join(seperator, arr);
}
```

And then use like this:

```cs
var list = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};
var output = list.Join(",");
// "A,B,C"
```

#### [Demo in .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4HMObc)