# linq ToArray<string>().Join(...) method is not working?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatble with `one` column

I want to concat each filename with wrapper div

something like :

```
    <div>File Attached : file1 </div>
    <div>File Attached : file2 </div>
    <div>File Attached : file3 </div>
...
```

I have succedded with :

```
 string f = String.Join(" ", (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                                 select "<div>File Attached : " + dr[0].ToString() + "</div>").ToArray<string>());
```

but **didnt** success with   :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCKLD.jpg
[image]

How can i do it with the .`Join` method after the `ToArray` method ?

Comment: .Join() method equals to SQL JOIN statement. You need .Aggregate() to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Join` is not the same as `String.Join` as you have discovered. `Enumerable.Join` works like joining in databases (but still on local objects, Queryable.Join works with SQL.) An example is given here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675.aspx

You could (but I **don't** recommend it because it will be ambiguous to the user) write an extension method like this:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public string Join(this IEnumerable<string> source, string sep)
    {
        return string.Join(sep, source.ToArray()); // You can erase `.ToArray()` if you're using .Net 4
    }
}
```

and then it would work with `(...).Join(" ")`.

**My solution: (4.0)**

```
var query = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable() // You may be able to erase `AsEnumerable` depending on your source
            select "<div>File Attached : " + dr[0] + "</div>";
var f = string.Join(" ", query);
```

**My solution: (3.5)**

```
var arr = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .Select(dr => "<div>File Attached : " + dr[0] + "</div>")
            .ToArray();
var f = string.Join(" ", arr);
```

Comment: oh sh*t  , is it the sql join  for linq?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, to get the same result using LINQ you should use `.Aggregate(...)`, but it's more difficult and less clear than `string.Join`

Comment: Yes, and `Aggregate` is inefficient with the naive `+` solution as given in another answer. **Always use `string.Join`.**

Comment: @lasseespeholt , OK but doesnt Array type has his own Join method ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir No, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484464/array-join-in-net . `Join` is only an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that that the Join function is the correct one? It sounds like you could be using the `Aggregate` function to end up with the same result, like this:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Aggregate(string.Empty, (x,y) => x + string.Format("<div>File Attached : {0} </div>", y));
```

Comment: OK but doesnt Array type has his own Join method ?