# .NET equivalent of JavaScript Array.join()

Tags: .net, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Array.Join in .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484464/array-join-in-net)

From a `List<String>` that contains `"Hello"` and `"World"`, I would like to obtain `"Hello, World"`.

Is there a library function that would accept my list and and the string `", "` and return `"Hello, World"` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is: not surprisingly, it is called [`Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h8wc12c.aspx)

```
String.Join(", ", new string[] {"hello", "world"});
```

In .NET 4.0 and later, the second parameter could be an `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Actually, in .NET 4 they added `params` to [`String.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.100).aspx) so you can do `String.Join(", ", "hello", "world");` without the `new string[] { ... }` part ;)

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in the List class

Answer (score 4):

Yes; `String.Join(separator, array)`

Comment: Thanks, I was looking in the List class

Answer (score 0):

```
string.join(yourlist.ToArray())
```

Comment: Please make sure to provide *valid* code.