# How to join strings from a list together in one string?

Tags: vb.net, string

### Issue

---

I have a list of strings which could be anything from 1 to 25 strings long. I want to get the values off each index and add them a string so that I can send an email listing the values in the list.

Here is the list of strings:

```
Dim DataSyncFiles As List(Of String) = {"COPOR1P", "FFBIVDP", "FFCHLDP", "FFDBKDP", "FFDREQP", "FFINVHP", "FFJACCP", "FFJACPP", "FFJMNEP", "FFJOBSP", "FFPIVHP", "FFUNTTP", "FJBJB1P", "FJBJM1P", "FJBJM2P", "FJBJU1P", "FJBNT2P", "FPPBE9P", "FSANO1P", "FTPCP1P", "FTTEG1P", "FTTEO1P", "FTTRQ1P", "XATXTDP", "FFADDRP", "FFLOCNP"}.ToList()
```

So i want to loop through these and add them to one single string (string below). The list above is not always going to be 26 strings long.

```
Dim files as string
```

How am i best to do this?

Comment: [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) will do this for you

Comment: @Steve How do I go about implementing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.Join in .Net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484464/array-join-in-net)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple [string.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
fileList = string.Join("", DataSyncFiles)
```

The first parameter is the separator to use between the single elements of DataSyncFiles. If you don't need it just pass an empty string or Nothing

Comment: Yes this works thanks. It's just a simple one line way and that's what i needed :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use [String.Join(string, IEnumerable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) to concat several strings to one big string

Answer (score 0):

```
For i as integer = 0 to DataSyncFiles.Length - 1
    files &= IIf(files <> "","," & filesDataSyncFiles(i),filesDataSyncFiles(i))
End For
```

Isnt a simple for loop required like this?

Comment: Yeah, i was seeing if there was a simple one line way of achieving this. If not i would have to make a loop.